# Flume Metrics through REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, flume, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm running hortonworks 2.3 and currently hooking into the REST API through ambari to start/stop the flume service and also submit configurations.
This is all working fine, My issue is how do I get the metrics?
Previously I used to run an agent with the parameters to produce the metrics to a http port and then read them in from there using this:

```
-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
-Dflume.monitoring.type=http
-Dflume.monitoring.port=XXXXX
```

However now that Ambari kicks off the agent I no longer have control over this.
Any assistance appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using Ambari 2.6.2.0,
http://{ipadress}:8080/api/v1/clusters/{your_cluster_name}/components/?ServiceComponentInfo/component_name=FLUME_HANDLER&fields=host_components/metrics/flume/flume
gives flume metrics breakdown by components. 
Found the answer by giving a shot (and doing some cropping) to the API call provided to this JIRA issue (which complains about how slow fetching flume metrics is) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-9914?attachmentOrder=asc 
Hope this helps.

Comment: links can die over time can you describe the details posted from the link in your answer

Comment: The link contains the API call address. It is not actually related to this question. Just mentioned it as a source of info. Added a short info about the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer. That happens because Hortonworks, by default, disable JSON monitoring, they use their own metric class to send the metrics to Ambari Metrics. While you can't retrieve it from Flume directly, you still can retrieve it from Ambari REST API: https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md.

Good luck,

Comment: Yeah I've been able to find some Metrics within the Ambari Api here: http://<ipaddress>:8080/api/v1/clusters/hdpdev/services/FLUME/components/FLUME_HANDLER but they appear to be grouped up to give you the sum of the metrics for all channels, or all sinks, or all sources. Previously I used to be able to see all the metrics on a more granular level - for each individual component.